# How to read session-timout from web.xml

Tags: servlets

How can i read the `session-timeout` from the web.xml file?

Tried

```
getServletContext().getAttribute("session-timeout").toString();
```

but gives me `NullPointerException`.

Also tried

```
getServletConfig().getInitParameter("session-timeout");
```

But gives me null because obviously this is not an `init-param`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an oneliner.

```
int sessionTimeoutFromWebXml = Integer.parseInt(XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("web-app/session-config/session-timeout").evaluate(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml"))));
```

;)

Comment: Since this code is a little involved, is there a way rather to set the value in the web.xml from a `public` `static` variable? Or to set the value from the `contextInitialized` method of the `ContextListener`? This way, I only write this value in one place.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
   session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
```

It will return time in seconds.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that, but is there a way to read that property from the web.xml as is?

Comment: Even I was wondering how can a person with such good reputation doesn't know about it ;). Well I guess we have to read whole xml file, find the session-timeout element and then check the value. I am not quite sure about it. Maybe experts over here can help both of us

Comment: and actually the `getMaxInactiveInterval()` returns the time in seconds

Comment: Its a bit weird that the information is stored in minutes and all you can get back is seconds.